# Typecast of return value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, casting, return

> function countdown(n){
> return n<=0?new Array():countdown(n-1).push(n); }

Here my code should push a value through recursion.
Only if the value is greater than 0.

The problem i encounter is .push() function is not recognize since function countdown
return value is an unknown type.

Is there a way in javascript to typecast my return value, so it will recognize .push() function

Comment: Yeah, true, i checked my code and i only get what i have pushed :). Thank you

Comment: Are you trying to write a recursive function that returns an array of n consecutive elements?

Comment: `push()` does return a number, not an array. Therefore `countdown(n-1)` returns a number at some point, which doesn't have a `.push()` method.

Comment: function countdown(n){
  if (n<=0) return new Array();
  let a = countdown(n-1);  
  a.unshift(n);
  return a;
}

Comment: @Ramesh Reddy yes i am trying, but base on my code im only returning the current pushed value.

Comment: But, although  my problem has been resolved. I want to ask whether it is possible for javascript to have a typecast on return value.

Comment: @BronxBranx Sure you can typecast the return value, like `return String(…)`, but that doesn't really help here. You cannot get the array back from the number.

Comment: @Bergi I already resolved my problem, Ramesh pinpointed the issue 3 minutes after i posted my inquiry.

Answer (score 0):

```
function countdown(n){ return n<=0?new Array():countdown(n-1).push(n); }
```

this recursive function doesn't work because `Array.prototype.push` returns the length of the array but not the array itself.

You can check the behaviour by passing 1 as the argument. Anything greater than 1 will throw an error as the recursive function will try to call push on a number.

```js
function countdown(n) {
  return n <= 0 ? new Array() : countdown(n - 1).push(n);
}

console.log(countdown(1))
```

Here's an alternative to get an array of n elements.

```js
function countdown(n, arr = []) {
  if (n <= 0) return arr;
  arr.push(n)
  return countdown(n - 1, arr);
}

console.log(countdown(2))
```

Answer (score 0):

[`push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) does return the new length - a number, not an array. Therefore `countdown(n-1)` returns a number at some point, which doesn't have a `.push()` method.

You can use

```
function countdown(n) {
    if (n <= 0) {
        return [];
    } else {
        const result = countdown(n-1);
        result.push(n);
        return result;
    }
}
```

or use `.concat()` instead of `push()`

```
function countdown(n) {
    return n <= 0 ? [] : countdown(n-1).concat([n]);
}
```

or spread syntax

```
function countdown(n) {
    return n <= 0 ? [] : [...countdown(n-1), n]);
}
```

but the latter two would have `O(n²)` time complexity due to the repeated copying of elements into a new array. Even more efficient than the `push` solution would be a non-recursive function

```
function countdown(n) {
    return Array.from({length: n}, (_, i) => i);
}
```